# if(scanner.nextInt){} is ignored (java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is a homework assignment. I have to write a program that outputs a text with exactly 8 characters (add spaces if there aren't enough, delete characters if there are too much) and then adds up to 30 "#" characters between "|" lines, dependent on the given value. The value can be int or double, int inputs range from 0 - 30 and double from 0.00 to 1.00.
An int of 30 or a double of 1.00 equals 30 "#" characters.
An int of 15 or a double of 0.50 equals 15 "#" characters.
The input can be in one line or multiple lines.

> example
>  input
>  WS2009 15
>  output
>      WS2009  *2 spaces
>   here* |############### *15 spaces here*              |

That's what I have cooked up so far:

> http://pastebin.com/LCuASiuD

The unnecessary `println()` and detours with `int1` and `double1` are for testing reasons.

The problem is, that the if and the else if condition are never called. I know since the outputs "int" or "dubs" never appear when I try it. What am I doing wrong? After `string1 = scanner1.next();` the next element should be an integer or a double. Is it because of the space?

```
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string1 = "";
    int int1 = 0;
    double double1 = 0;


    while(scanner1.hasNext())
    {   
        string1 = scanner1.next();
        System.out.println(string1);

        if(scanner1.hasNextInt())
        {
            int1 = scanner1.nextInt();
            System.out.println(drawBar(string1 , int1));
            System.out.println("int");
        }
        else if(scanner1.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double1 = scanner1.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(drawBar(string1 , double1));
            System.out.println("dubs");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's actually nothing wrong with this, as far as we can see -- it should work fine.  Based on that suspicion, I compiled your source from pastebin and ran it, and indeed, it worked just as expected.  I sense a real head-desk collision scenario coming up.

Comment: Since I don't get the formating I made a screenshot of what I wanted to answer. http://666kb.com/i/c2lsyi21l0tfp7wuu.png

Comment: I just found out that it works if the value is an integer, it doesn't work if it's a double!

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:
The german seperator for decimal places is a "," and my editor/JDK or whatever uses this local default and expects a "," but this input numbers are seperated with a ".". Now I got to find out how to fix this.
I cant answer my own problem because I am a new user.

Comment: You can use this to execute it: java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US test2 Besides that the treatment of the double was totally wrong anyways and I didn't add the reactions to unexpected input yet.